# How to run an android application horizontally or vertically in emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to change the display direction of the Android emulator that comes within the Eclipse bundle.

How do I change it horizontally or vertically?

Comment: please, accept answers if you feel that they answer your question. Also before asking a question, please search the database of the answer. Also take a look a FAQ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Switch to previous layout orientation (for example, portrait, landscape)
`KEYPAD_7, Ctrl-F11`

Switch to next layout orientation (for example, portrait, landscape)
`KEYPAD_9, Ctrl-F12`

Comment: is there any way like the view perspective in the emulator can be changed. ?

Comment: hmmm? the emulator display is vertical, but the OS in starts horizontally.

Comment: You might want to check the startup options mentioned in the emulator manual I linked. Haven't tried those.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl + F12` if you're on a PC.

Comment: the application starts vertically where as it is suppose to be horizontal. any command?

Answer (score 1):

Run application on Emulator and Press `Ctrl + F11` to change `Potrait mode to LandScape` and `LandScape to Potrait .`

Answer (score 1):

When running ADK on Windows both Ctrl+F11 and Ctrl+F12 have the same effect which is switching back and forth between portrait and landscape orientations. Remember to release the Ctrl key every time or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add and set the screenOrientation attribute to 'landscape' on the manifest file for that specific activity

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```